# Drilldown navigation but retain also the orginal members in icCube on click drilldown chart

Tags: iccube

How to add the standard drilldown navigation to children ($member.children), but keep the orginal data as well. Preferable, as generic as possible, so I do not have to know what is on the rows at all (might be 1 hierarchy or a combination of multiple).

[image: explenation of this question]

Comment: Looks complicated: if you click again in number 3, what would happen ?

Comment: I think the only possiblity would be giving a javascript interface, is this really needed  ?

Comment: Is it really needed? ... Let me explain the business case.Consider you have a waterfall chart with data that is not fully expanded and you would like to expand a sub-total to see how this sub-total is constructed based on the children. In that case, you want the chart to be redrawn including the children of the sub-total. My idea was to use MDX: hierarchize(<original row axis> + $member.children, post). But I do not know how to refer to the <original row axis>. Is that even  possible at all?

Comment: not yet possible.

Comment: ok, clear. Thank you.

Comment: it will be part of the upcoming version ( adding $axis too as a parameter )

Comment: This is great news and totally unexpected. Again, many thanks. Could you add this to the solution of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the new release (6.6). You can now us $axis in the MDX expression :

```
$axis +$member.children
```

and a variant that shows only one drilldown path :

```
Filter($axis as t, t.currentMember.level_number <= $member.level_number)  + $member.children
```

The result is something like :

[image]

After clicking 2006:

[image]